# Ionic 3 login and checking statement in app.component.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, ionic3

I look over a lot login tutorial but neither one give me an answer on my question, how to check if user logged in or not.

I am interested if someone can show me, off course is it possible, how to check in main component (app.component.ts) when user change the page? So I want to check in one place when user is logged in or not, when is logged in than in storage exist token and can proceed, if is not to set rootPage to login page. In angular is great when you have guardService on route, but here is not possible to have that or am I wrong. Anyhow can someone helps me how to check when user change the page is logged in or not and if is possible to do that in app.component.ts

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import {SplashScreen} from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import {Platform, NavController, MenuController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

import {SigninPage} from '../pages/auth/signin/signin';
import {SignupPage} from "../pages/auth/signup/signup";
import {AuthService} from "../services/auth";
import {HomePage} from "../pages/home/home";
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
    rootPage:any = HomePage;
    signinPage = SigninPage;
    signupPage = SignupPage;
    isAuthenticated = false;
    @ViewChild('nav') nav:NavController;

    constructor(platform:Platform, statusBar:StatusBar,
                splashScreen:SplashScreen,
                private menuCtrl:MenuController,
                private authService:AuthService,
                private storage:Storage) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
            // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
            statusBar.styleDefault();
            splashScreen.hide();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily if you maintain the status of the user inside the `storage` module. Then you can check like below.

*app.component.ts*

```
constructor(private storage: Storage) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
     this.storage.get('loggedInUser')
        .then((res: any) => {
          if (res) {//do whatever you want};
        }, () => {
        });
    });
```

**Note:**

If you need more advance solution here then you can check the [**official app here**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app):

Comment: Is this solution only when application start or for all states ?

Comment: This is for app start.But If you have `this.storage.get('loggedInUser')` then you can get that value throughout your app no.

Comment: But I have to do that in every page.ts, I want to if exist some solution to check that on one page, in app.component.ts for every time when page is changed

Comment: If you need more advance solution here then you can check the official app here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app